How old is Nate Heywood in DC's Legends of Tomorrow?
In the show DC's Legends of Tomorrow, we see Nate Heywood travel through time with the Legends, and we also see him age a little bit, so how old is he? He might be in his mid-30's and early 40s, but it's not revealed, and his DOB is not disclosed in the show. In season 2, it looks like he was de-aged from his late 20s and early 30s, but in season 7, we see him age throughout the series.
